# How can I get sim id of the sim that is used when calling on a phone with dual sim?

Tags: android, dual-sim

This is what I would do normally to get the sim id:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/16242734/5292302 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472951/get-both-sim-numbers-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: I want to display the details  during calling of the calling sim not the other sim but I don't know how to fetch id of calling sim